# TypeScript / Angular import library which extends NameSpace

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I'm trying to use Leaflet (https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet) together with this non-npm library (https://github.com/Sumbera/gLayers.Leaflet) in my Angular 4 app.

I have declared the Leaflet 'L' namespace by "import * as L from 'leaflet';" in my component, did the cli-loading-stuff and everything from this package works.

The problem now is, the second library (which i loaded in angular cli under scripts after leaflet.js) should extend 'L' by 'L.canvasLayer', but if i call it, console says its not a function and it does not seem to exists. How can I get it to load? Thanks for help!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I guess you did not find a solution to it yet?

Comment: Any chance you guys found an elegant way to do this?